# Remote debugging running process inside docker container

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, docker, remote-debugging, docker-compose

I'm running a node.js application inside a `Docker` container. I need to debug this application with `Intellij Ultimate 15`.

```
demoapp:
  build: .
  command: 'bash -c "npm install && npm run debug"'
  ports:
    - "8989:8989"
  environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 'demoapp.docker'
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8989
```

The `debug` script from `package.json`

```
"debug": "(node-inspector --web-port=8989  app.js &) && node --debug app.js"
```

And the configuration in the IDE

[image]

The IDE responds with a `Frame is not available`. I guess it couldn't connect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Moreover, I'm able to debug using `Chrome`. If I visit the `demoapp.docker:8989` it connects and I can start debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect to the debug port via IntelliJ debugger, not to the web port. So you should specify it (with the `--debug` option) on the node runtime and expose it to the docker host and after that you'll be able to connect to it.

More info in the JetBrains documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#remote_debugging